# How to paste a column from one sheet below another sheet? Both columns are of equal but unknown length

Tags: excel, vba

What I successfully did:

I was able to paste the column starting from F2 on "Sheet1" onto the sheet "Load File because I know the column will begin at E2.

What I am struggling with:

I need to copy the same column, add 28 to each value in the column (the values are dates), and paste the result right below the column I just pasted

This is the code I've tried. The first bit works as I've mentioned

```
'Developement Complete

Set ws = Application.Worksheets("Sheet1")
endRowSheet1 = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Set wsOut = Application.Worksheets("Load File")

Set r = ws.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(endRowSheet1, 1))
    r.Copy
    wsOut.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

Set r = ws.Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(endRowSheet1, 6))
    r.Copy
    wsOut.Range("E2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

endRowDevelopment = wsOut.UsedRange.Rows.Count
'Compliance Regulatory
'need to add 28 to the value in each cell of copied column

Set r = ws.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(endRow, 1))
    r.Copy
    wsOut.Range(Cells(endRowDevelopment + 1, 1), Cells(endRowDevelopment * 2 + 1, 1)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

Set r = ws.Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(endRow, 6))
    r.Copy
    wsOut.Range(Cells(endRowDevelopment + 1, 5), Cells(endRowDevelopment * 2 + 1, 5)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End Sub
```

I get runtime error 1004 so I suspect there's something wrong with how I am using the range function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cells refer to a particular sheet and need to be qualified by ".". Also, do not use UsedRange to count rows. If you delete rows in your destination sheet, they will remain in the UsedRange even if they are blank. Just count the rows in your sheet or in the column where you want to paste your values. Finally you can clean up the code a little if you just want to paste the dates.

```
Sub test()

Set ws = Application.Worksheets("Sheet1")

endRowSheet1 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set wsOut = Application.Worksheets("Load File")

With ws

Set r1 = ws.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(endRowSheet1, 1))
    r1.Copy Destination:=wsOut.Range("A2")

Set r2 = ws.Range(.Cells(2, 6), .Cells(endRowSheet1, 6))
    r2.Copy Destination:=wsOut.Range("E2")

End With

endRowDevelopment = wsOut.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    r1.Copy Destination:=wsOut.Range("A" & endRowDevelopment + 1)
    r2.Copy Destination:=wsOut.Range("E" & endRowDevelopment + 1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fully qualify all `Range` and `Cells` references with a worksheet (note the dots below):

```
With ws
    Set r = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(endRowSheet1, 1))
    r.Copy
    wsOut.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Set r = ws.Range(.Cells(2, 6), .Cells(endRowSheet1, 6))
    r.Copy
    wsOut.Range("E2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    endRowDevelopment = wsOut.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set r = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(endRow, 1))
    r.Copy
    wsOut.Range(wsOut.Cells(endRowDevelopment + 1, 1), wsOut.Cells(endRowDevelopment * 2 + 1, 1)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Set r = .Range(.Cells(2, 6), .Cells(endRow, 6))
    r.Copy
    wsOut.Range(wsOut.Cells(endRowDevelopment + 1, 5), wsOut.Cells(endRowDevelopment * 2 + 1, 5)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
end with
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! When I run this code, I get runtime error 91. After some googling I think it has to do with the Set statements. Do you know how to get by this?

Comment: On which line ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check? after the error message pops up, there is no line highlighted in the code

Comment: Try stepping through your code using F8. Have all the variables been defined (given values)? In the last 2 pastes you might try changing the destination cell so the top cell only (rather than a range), though don't think that would cause that error.

Comment: In fact rxex's answer is better so try that.

Comment: Done! Didn't realize that was an option haha